# clientcontext and formdigest

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've added <`SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"  />` to my custom aspx page (spd) but can't get the current context with :

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

It only works for relative url's,, but how can I get the current site at runtime without hardwiring ?

```
function retrieveListItems() {
var siteUrl = '/sites/IAhub/sample';

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); // fails

//  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); //works

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Mandays');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}
```

Here is the entire code (Please note I am not inheriting the master page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>




<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>

 <!-- the following 5 js files are required to use CSOM -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>

    <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"  />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


hello<br />

<a href="#" onclick="retrieveListItems();">Get Items</a>

<script type="text/javascript">



function retrieveListItems() {
var siteUrl = '/sites/IAhub/sample';

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

//  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Mandays');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title');
                }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
});

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Javascript Object Model `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` call relies on a window property `window._spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl` which is filled in by the default implementation of SharePoint masterpages

If you're using a custom aspx page you should provide this variable to the window in javascript from your aspx code if you want to use the `get_current()` function

Answer (score 0):

Suspect it is an issue with MDS

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
});

function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();       
}
```

Comment: Hi Amal Code makes no difference

Comment: Error: Unable to get value of the property 'webServerRelativeUrl': object is null or undefined

Comment: I'm not using the masterpage and added FormDigest in the head section of the page. Updating with entire code.

Comment: @OrangeJuice I think you can dynamically create context using `var clientContext  = new SP.ClientContext(window.location.href);`

Comment: The reason why I've omitted the master page is because its adds the ribbon and I want to open this page in a dialog box.. Is there another way where the opage can be opened in a dialog without showing master page artefacts?

Comment: Yes you can place query string `IsDlg=1`   http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2013/11/sp2013-hiding-the-ribbon-in-dialog-view/